# Continuous Time Markov chain

Tags: matrix, generator

What is the intuition behind 'Infinitesimal generator matrix?What why we need it?Why it is called generator matrix?what it generates?

Comment: Have you tried [searching our site?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=infinitesimal%20generator%20markov)

Comment: I tried,but my question is not the same one sir!It's different!

Comment: Please then, clarify what your question is (you ask four of them in this post) and how it differs from any of the answered ones.

Comment: I asked four questions on the same topic (Continuous time markov chain) Sir!I didn’t ask for the solve of kolmogorov  forward equation related questions.I came here with a lot of hope, but you guys closed my question by saying It's already answered! That's really disappointing!

Comment: You are less likely to be disappointed if you learn how this site works.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions would be a good place to begin.